# NumPy: Error While Concatenation - zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to concat two valid array via `np.concat()` method.

My code:

```py
print X_train.shape, train_names.shape
X_train = np.concatenate([train_names,X_train], axis=0)
```

The output:

```py
    (3545, 93355) (3545, 692)


    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-58-59dc66874663> in <module>()
      1 print X_train.shape, train_names.shape
    ----> 2 X_train = np.concatenate([train_names,X_train], axis=0)
      

    ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

As you can see, the shapes of arrays align, still I am getting this weird error. Why?

EDIT: I have tried with `axis=1` as well. Same result

EDIT 2: Eqauted data types using `.astype(np.float64)`. Same result.

Comment: I would also check the `dtype` of the inputs.  Something in the input to the `np.concatenate` is `zero-dimensional`.  We can't see it, but you will if you add enough diagnostic prints.

Comment: I tried equating dtypes. Still same result. Maybe it is a bug with my version of Numpy 1.10.4. Plausible?

Comment: Does this work with smaller arrays?

Comment: I tried for with smaller matrix. It was working. This tipped me off that something is essentially wrong with my matrix. I think my array might be a sparse matrix. That is why concat is not working.

Comment: By sparse do you mean lots of zeros, or the `scipy sparse matrix` type?  Since it works for smaller arrays, I suspect a memory or indexing issue.  We need to look for other `concatenate` error questions.

Comment: scipy.sparse. I am able to concat using hstack. This must be it,

Comment: If your arrays are `scipy sparse` don't use `np.concatenate`.  Only use `sparse` functions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Applying `np.concatenate` to `scipy` `sparse` matrices produces this error:

```
In [162]: from scipy import sparse
In [163]: x=sparse.eye(3)
In [164]: x
Out[164]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
In [165]: np.concatenate((x,x))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-165-0b67d0029ca6> in <module>()
----> 1 np.concatenate((x,x))

ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

There are `sparse` functions to do this:

```
In [168]: sparse.hstack((x,x)).A
Out[168]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
In [169]: sparse.vstack((x,x)).A
Out[169]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the arrays as a tuple rather than a list.
`X_train = np.concatenate((train_names,X_train), axis=0)`

Comment: In this context list and tuples are treated the same.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was due to sparse nature of matrix returned by LabelEncoder()

so this line gave me an error:

```
np.append(airlineTrain, train_transformed,axis =1)
```

To fix it, I used this:

```
np.append(airlineTrain.toarray(), train_transformed.toarray(),axis =1 )
```

Alternately, you may be using NLTK, where the sparse storage of matrices can be converted by using `todense()`